# Change the Windows folder permissions to Read only from Python

Tags: python, readonly, folder-permissions

I have a test case to automate, where in I need to change the folder's permission to read only from Python script. I am using Test Complete tool with python scripting for automating the manual tests.

I am not able to accomplish the tasks, I tried Googling but no luck.

Comment: @DYZ, your google is illegal))

Comment: _I tried googling but no luck._ --> So you already have some code that you tried but that code failed? Please [edit] your question and show us your code and the exception that you got.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line of code.

```
import os, stat

os.chmod(ur"file_path_name", stat.S_IREAD)
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck. I am able to create a new file/folder in the path after running the above code also :(